# date + time from vb6 to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb6

I have this code in VB6

```
  Dim datahorS As String
  datahorS = Text21.text & " " & Text22.text
  Label2.Caption = datahorS
  SQL = " insert into  TabNFe_x ( data_hora_ent) values " _
  & "(" & "'" & datahorS & "'" & ")"
```

datahorS = 20/10/2016 13:54
and the command

```
insert into  TabNFe_x ( data_hora_ent) values ('20/10/2016 13:54')
```

erro from SQL

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

what's i m making wrong.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection, you need to rewrite this to use a parameterized insert.  This will also have the advantage of correctly handling a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your string into a datetime

```
Select convert(datetime, '20/10/2016 13:54', 103)
```

Returns

```
2016-10-20 13:54:00.000
```